# Decimal point dissapear on input text using LG keyboard

Tags: angular, mobile, keyboard, lg

I have an app made in Angular. I have an input field like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model" 
       name="import" 
       type="number" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="inputOilPrice" 
       min="0.0">
```

When I try to enter a value with a LG X Power the keyboard that is shown dont have decimal separator (with other devices works fine). I also try to put the step to any.

Also changing the keyboard solves the problem.

Comment: Maybe LG has some system where you can file a bug?

Comment: But is there any way to avoid that behaviour withotu changing the type of the input field?